# Calculate mean of a proportion of the data.frame

Tags: r

I'm working with data that looks similar to this:

```
cat    value  n
  1      100 18
  2        0 19
  3     -100 15
  4      100 13
  5        0 17
  6     -100 18
```

In the real data, there are many `cat`s and `value` can be any number between -100 and 100 (no `NA`).

What I want to do is to calculate the mean of `value` based on terciles defined by `n`

So, for example, since `sum(n)=100` what I want to do is to get `n`'s as close as possible to 33 and calculate the mean of `value`. So for the first tercile, 18 isn't quite 33, so I need to take 15 values from `cat`=2. So the mean for the first tercile should be `(100*18+0*15)/(18+15)`. The second tercile would be the remaining `n`s from `cat`=2, then as many as are needed to get to 33: `(0*4+-100*15+100*13+0*1)/(4+15+13+1)`. Similar for the last tercile.

I got started writing this, but ended up with lots of nasty `for` loops and `if` statements. I'm hoping that you see an easier way to deal with this than I do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not quite clear what `cat2` is, it's not in your data example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second value of `cat`. I'll put in an equals sign

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get what the OP is asking?

Comment: @SabDeM it's a strange question. I tried explain, but what are you confused about?

Comment: I compared the speed using a data frame with 100 rows. The accepted answer 1 is the slowest, 10 times slower than answer 3 and 100 times slower than answer 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, `data` being your example dataframe:

```
    longData<-unlist(apply(data[,c("value","n")],1,function(x){
      rep(x["value"],x["n"])      
    }))

    aggregate(longData,list(cut(seq_along(longData),breaks=3,right=FALSE)),mean)
```

`longData` will be a vector of length 100 with, using your example, 18 repetitions of -100, 19 repetitions of 0 etc.

The `cut` in the `aggregate` will divide `longData` into three groups, and the mean of each group will be calculated.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[rep(1:.N,n)
          ][,indx:=c(rep("a",33),rep("b",33),rep("c",34))
            ][,.(mean_val_indx=mean(value)),by=indx]
```

this gives:

```
   indx mean_val_indx
1:    a     54.545455
2:    b     -6.060606
3:    c    -52.941176
```

Which are the means of `value` for the three parts of the data.

---

Broken down in the intermediate steps:

**1**: replice the rows according `n`

```
setDT(df)[rep(1:.N,n)]
```

this gives (shortened):

```
     cat value  n
  1:   1   100 18
  2:   1   100 18
....
 17:   1   100 18
 18:   1   100 18
 19:   2     0 19
 20:   2     0 19
....
 36:   2     0 19
 37:   2     0 19
 38:   3  -100 15
....
 99:   6  -100 18
100:   6  -100 18
```

**2**: create an index with `[,indx:=c(rep("a",33),rep("b",33),rep("c",34))]`

```
setDT(df)[rep(1:.N,n)
          ][,indx:=c(rep("a",33),rep("b",33),rep("c",34))]
```

this gives:

```
> dt
     cat value  n indx
  1:   1   100 18    a
  2:   1   100 18    a
....
 17:   1   100 18    a
 18:   1   100 18    a
 19:   2     0 19    a
 20:   2     0 19    a
....
 32:   2     0 19    a
 33:   2     0 19    a
 34:   2     0 19    b
 35:   2     0 19    b
....
 99:   6  -100 18    c
100:   6  -100 18    c
```

**3**: summarise `value` by `indx` with `[,.(mean_val_indx=mean(value)),by=indx]`

Comment: I like the data.table example, but what if the index needs to be different lengths (for example, a=66, b=67, c=67

Comment: @Alex Look at the code in step 2, and you cn see that it's quite easy to change to length of the index. Just change the numbers. It's quite logical that the length of the index is the same as the length of the data table. Under what circustance would the length be different?

Answer (score 0):

If already the data is very long repetition by "n" is perhaps unwanted.
The following solution doesn't do this. Moreover, 1/3 of the sum of the
"n"-values is not rounded to the nearest integer.
"i" is the vector of row numbers where terciles end. Since it is possible
that several terciles end at the same row, those row numbers are replicated.
The result is the vector "k".
For each index "j" the cumulative sum of "data$value"*"data$n" up to "k[j]"
covers "ms[k[j]]" terciles, so "ms[j]-j" terciles have to be subtracted
to get the cumulative sum up to the "j"th tercile.

```
m <- 3

sn <- sum(data$n)
ms <- m * cumsum(data$n) / sn
d  <- diff(c(0,floor(ms)))
i  <- which(d>0)
k  <- rep(i,d[i])
vn <- data$value * data$n

sums  <- cumsum(vn)[k] - (ms[k]-(1:m))*data$value[k]*sn/m
means <- m*diff(c(0,sums))/sn
```

The means of the terciles are:

```
> means
[1]  54  -6 -54
```

In this example "i" is equal to "k". But if terciles are replaced by deciles,
i.e. "m" is not 3 but 10, they are distinct:

```
> m
[1] 10
> i
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> k
 [1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 6
> means
 [1]  100   80    0  -30 -100   60   50    0  -80 -100
```

I compared the speed of the 4 answers, using out small example with 8 rows:

```
> ##### "longData"-Answer #####
> 
> system.time( for ( i in 1:1000 ) { A1 <- f1(data) } )
       User      System verstrichen 
       3.48        0.00        3.49 

> ##### "sapply"-Answer #####
> 
> system.time( for ( i in 1:1000 ) { A2 <- f2(data) } )
       User      System verstrichen 
       1.00        0.00        0.99 

> ##### "data.table"Answer #####
> 
> system.time( for ( i in 1:1000 ) { A3 <- f3(data) } )
       User      System verstrichen 
       4.73        0.00        4.79 

> ##### this Answer #####
> 
> system.time( for ( i in 1:1000 ) { A4 <- f4(data) } )
       User      System verstrichen 
       0.43        0.00        0.44
```

The "sapply"-Answer is even false:

```
> A1
     Group.1          x
1 [0.901,34)  54.545455
2    [34,67)  -6.060606
3   [67,100) -52.941176
> A2
    (0,33]    (33,67]   (67,100] 
-100.00000    0.00000   93.93939 
> A3
   indx mean_val_indx
1:    a     54.545455
2:    b     -6.060606
3:    c    -52.941176
> A4
[1]  54  -6 -54
>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is basically the same as NicE although perhaps useful as a different way fo assembling the rep and cutting operations:

```
 sapply(split( sort(unlist( mapply(rep, res$value, res$n) )), 
               cut(seq(sum(res$n)), breaks=c(0,33,67,100) )), 
        mean)

    (0,33]    (33,67]   (67,100] 
-100.00000    0.00000   93.93939
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The result is simply wrong, even if the "n"-values sum up to 100.

Comment: We obviously understood the question very  differently. My interpretation was that the OP asked for the means of the items (formed by replicating the values by the counts in "n") broken up into roughly equal sizes. It was not what I understand to be the statistical meaning of `terciles` but rather how I understood the intent of the questioner from the context of the question (and now from the OP's comments).

Comment: If you understood the question differently, why did you say that NicE's solution and yours were basically the same? They are definitely NOT the same.

Comment: Well, now that I have run his solution to which he didn't post output I see they are different. Feel free to invite all your friends to continue down voting.